# ADF BC App Module Service Interface Returns StackOverflowError

Tags: web-services, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I created a Service Interface in my Application Module for two View Object instances. The view object instances represent the Employees and Departments table of the Default Oracle Database schema, HR. I have the following Basic operations selected in my Service Interface for both View Object Instances: Update, GetByKey, Find.

When I run the web service and test it via JDeveloper HTTP Analyzer or The web service's endpoint service in my browser, I always get the error below:

**Exception while executing the business logic: what do i do: seems an odd quirk of the EJB spec.  The exception is:java.lang.StackOverflowError.**

When i send a proper SOAP Request over to the web service, i get the following soap message back:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><env:Fault><faultcode>env:Server</faultcode><faultstring>what do i do: seems an odd quirk of the EJB spec.  The exception is:java.lang.StackOverflowError</faultstring></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

There's nothing else helpful on this error unfortunately.

Any ideas? All i used was the JDeveloper wizards to create this...

I'm using JDeveloper 11.1.2.4 (11gR2).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have all the FKs? There are 3 between Dept and Emp:
EmpDept, DeptMgr, EmpMgr.
I found that the EMpMgr can cause the stack overflow if I'm getting children.
Do you need that FK? if not, try deleting the assoc/link for this and redeploy and test.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks! I noticed, whenever i create a Service Interface with one view instance or the the other, it works great. But bring in both view instances together, you get stack overflow.

Comment: You the man! It works after I removed the FK View Link and Assocation.

Comment: glad it worked - it bit me on the butt at first too - very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!! it's of great help to me and saved lot of time. In my case, i had to remove DeptMgr FKLink too. May be this is because of the reason that i exposed services on both Emp and Dept VOs.